# Alignment of ASP.NET label

Tags: asp.net, css

I have created an ASP.NET master page as follows:

```
<body class="MasterStyle">
  <form id="frmMaster" runat="server">
  <div>        
    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="My Site Name" Font-Bold="true" Font-Names="MS-Sans" 
            Style="text-align:right" Width="100%" />
```

The style is defined as follows:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .MasterStyle
    {
        width: 100%;
        background: aqua;
    }
```

The problem is that “My Site Name” is appearing just off the right hand site of the page (just missing the “e” off).  Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: Try adding padding right with few pixels

Comment: why are you setting width 100% on your body, take that off

Comment: If I don't set the width on the style then it doesn't use the full width of the web page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `body` margin.  Because the margin is taking up space, and you are making the `Label` 100%, it is not accounting for the margin offset so your text is pushed over by that amount.

To fix it, just change `.MasterStyle to:

```
.MasterStyle 
{ 
    width: 100%; 
    background: aqua;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

I have tested this and it fixes your issue but it does remove the margin offset which makes things not space from the edges nicely.

If you want to change more you can keep the margin by removing the `Width` property from your `Label` and the `.MasterStyle` and then adding a `float: right` style to the `div`.

```
.MasterStyle 
{ 
    background: aqua;
}

<body class="MasterStyle">
    <form id="frmMaster" runat="server">
        <div style="float: right">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="My Site Name"
                Font-Bold="true" Font-Names="MS-Sans" Style="text-align:right" />
```

Either way will work, just depending on if you want the margins or not.

Comment: Thanks for that!  In the end I just reduced the width to 95% which seemed to solve the problem, and let me still keep the width with the style.

Answer (score 0):

Because of text-align:right.
Remove from style.

Comment: Opps sorry. I understand your question wrongly.
So just put float:left; in your .masterstyle. or try width:99%